# Getting parse error but I can't see anythting wrong in the line

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
if($_POST['format'] == "csv")
{
Line 174 -> $objWriter = new PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
         $objWriter->save($FNAME);

} else {
         $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
         $objWriter->save($FNAME);
}
```

I am getting parse error: "`( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in B:\wamp\www\SuperPages\action.php on line 174`" but I can't see anything wrong."

Comment: You probably want to remove the `new` keyword, as `::createWriter` looks like its doing the actual `new` and returning the created object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "new". The `createWriter()` is static method.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV')
```

Looks like a factory method, which I would guess creates the object you want and returns it to you. However, you're using `new` on it, which you would do if you were creating the object yourself... and not the factory method.

Therefore, just remove `new` from that line.